# Google Geocoding API Unexpected Result on ambiguous search query

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I use google geocoding API to realize a autocomplete search for location within a customized Map. 
I do a request like that:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=frankfurt&components=country[de]

I got back this response with just one result:

```
    {
      results: [
        {
          address_components: [
            {
              long_name: "Frankfurt am Main",
              short_name: "Frankfurt am Main",
              types: [
                "locality",
                "political"
              ]
            },
            {
              long_name: "Darmstadt",
              short_name: "DA",
              types: [
                "administrative_area_level_2",
                "political"
              ]
            },
            {
              long_name: "Hessen",
              short_name: "HE",
              types: [
                "administrative_area_level_1",
                "political"
              ]
            },
            {
              long_name: "Deutschland",
              short_name: "DE",
              types: [
                "country",
                "political"
              ]
            }
          ],
          formatted_address: "Frankfurt am Main, Deutschland",
          geometry: {
            bounds: {
              northeast: {
                lat: 50.2272095,
                lng: 8.8003977
              },
              southwest: {
                lat: 50.0152145,
                lng: 8.4727299
              }
            },
            location: {
              lat: 50.1109221,
              lng: 8.6821267
            },
            location_type: "APPROXIMATE",
            viewport: {
              northeast: {
                lat: 50.2272095,
                lng: 8.8003977
              },
              southwest: {
                lat: 50.0152145,
                lng: 8.4727299
              }
            }
          },
          place_id: "ChIJxZZwR28JvUcRAMawKVBDIgQ",
          types: [
            "locality",
            "political"
          ]
        }
      ],
      status: "OK"
    }
```

The Problem is, that the response should contain all Frankfurts that exist in Germany. (Frankfurt, Main + Frankfurt, Oder). But it just respond with Frankfurt, Main. The same thing happens on other place names, that in theory should exists at least twice. But google just shows one. Probably the most relevant one.

Is there a way to modify that? Or better use another Geocode service ?

I tried to use component filters, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Several things caught my eye in this question, xomena's answer covers all of them but one: country[de] is not correctly formatted and will be ignored, you need to use country=de

Answer (score 3):

This is an intended behavior of Geocoding API. The most prominent result will come back. However, you can use [Autocomplete request of Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) which can return up to 5 suggestions.

You can set a component filter by country and restrict types to cities. Please look at the following request:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Frankfurt&types=(cities)&components=country%3ADE&key=YOUR_API_KEY

This request returns both "Frankfurt, Germany" (place ID ChIJxZZwR28JvUcRAMawKVBDIgQ) and "Frankfurt an der Oder, Germany" (place ID ChIJb_u1AiqYB0cRwDteW0YgIQQ).

To dig further you can execute geocoding requests for each place ID:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?place_id=ChIJxZZwR28JvUcRAMawKVBDIgQ&key=YOUR_API_KEY

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?place_id=ChIJb_u1AiqYB0cRwDteW0YgIQQ&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Hope it helps.